# C# : multiplication identity, How do i get it to do that?

Tags: c#

A^2-B^2=(A-B)*(A+B) is the forumla i have.

The user is supposed to input A and B.

Lets say i put A as 4, and B as 2. A = 4, B = 2.
How do i get it to show up like this on my output screen? :

4^2 - 2^2 = (4-2)*(4+2)

16-4 = (2)*(6)

12 = 12

Comment: What's wrong with `Console.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there appears to be a typo in your question. Apparently your formula isn't `A^2-B^2=(A-B)+(A+B)`, as the beginning of your question suggests; the example shown is doing multiplication on the right-hand side of the equation.

Here's a very basic example of how to do this.

```
int a = ReadInt("Enter value for A: "); // see end of answer for `ReadInt` definitions
int b = ReadInt("Enter value for B: ");

Console.WriteLine("{0}^2-{1}^2=({0}-{1})*({0}+{1})", a, b);
Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1} = ({2})*({3})", a * a, b * b, a - b, a + b);
Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", a * a - b * b, (a - b) * (a + b));
```

The `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. in the output text are placeholders. They are explained in the MSDN article ["Composite Formatting"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx). Basically, the zero-based numbers inside the curly brackets specify which of the arguments after the format text (first argument to `Console.WriteLine`) will be printed in their place.

The above code makes a reference to some `ReadInt` method. Here are two possible definitions for it:

- Unsafe, non-validating variant which will throw an exception if the users enters something other than an in-range integral number:

  ```
  static int ReadInt(string prompt)
  {
      Console.Write(prompt);
      return int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
  ```
- Safer, validating variant:

  ```
  static int ReadInt(string prompt)
  {
      for (;;)
      {
          Console.Write(prompt);
          int result;
          if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
          {
              return result;
          }
          else
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Invalid input! Please enter an integral number.");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: The whole task is to make the user input A and B. So the 4 and 2 change to what the user inputs. If i put the formula in Console.WriteLine( A^2-B^2=(A-B)+(A+B) ) all i get is a single number, but i need the 3 stages of it being calculated. ( Sorry for my bad english....)

Comment: @Armis: If substituting `A` and `B` *based on user input* is what you want to do, then you should state that in your question! (We cannot read your mind, after all.) Please edit it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: Thank you! Your a lifesaver :)